# Matching all links, except the ones at the beginning in parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract all link targets from a piece of text. So for example, from the following

```
data1 = '<a href="a"> a (d <a href="b"> f) b (<a href="c">) d <a href="d"> d(<a href="e">)'
```

I would like to get ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].

However, I would like to skip any links that are in parentheses and occur before a link that is not in parentheses. After the first link that is not in parentheses, parentheses become irrelevant and I would like to match all links. So, for the string

```
data2 = 'a (d <a href="b"> f) b (<a href="c">) d <a href="d"> d(<a href="e">)'
```

I would like to get ['d', 'e'].

I have tried using the regex module. The following expression captures all links (with and without parentheses):

```
regex.match('(?:.*?<a href="([^>])+">)*', data2).captures(1)
```

How can I skip initial links in parentheses?

Comment: Please clarify: in `data1`, `(<a href="c">)` is a link in parentheses and occurs before a link not in parentheses. Why is `'c'` in the output? And in `data2`, `(d <a href="b"> f)` does not occur before a link not in parentheses (the link following it is also in parentheses), so why is it not in the output?

Comment: I've tried to clarify it: I would like to ignore any links in parentheses before the first link that is not in parentheses. After that first link, parentheses don't matter anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the task is to drop links while they are inside parentheses, and then return all the links in the remainder. You can use the (aptly named) [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) in combination with regex.

Here's how I would do it:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

def get_links(s):
    without_paren = r'<a href="(?P<WITHOUT_PAREN>[^"]+)">'
    with_paren = r'\(.*?<a href="(?P<WITH_PAREN>[^"]+)">.*?\)'
    master_pattern = with_paren + '|' + without_paren  # try with_paren first
    it = re.finditer(master_pattern, s)
    # Drop matches in `it` until we hit the first without_paren match
    # and yield every match from there onwards
    for mo in dropwhile(lambda mo: mo.lastgroup == 'WITH_PAREN', it):
        yield mo.group(mo.lastgroup)
```

Trying this on your data:

```
>>> print(list(get_links(data1)))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> print(list(get_links(data2)))
['d', 'e']
```

People will usually tell you to parse HTML etc with specialized libraries and they are often right. HTML is not a regular language and regex can't really deal with it in its full complexity. But you seem to be dealing with a "regular" sort of data here, for which regex might just work.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing HTML is not an easy task, and not easily done with regexp, you'd better use a real HTML parser like html5lib which is really great. Once the HTML parsed you can spot interesting values with a simple state machine or whatever pleases you:

```
import html5lib

document = html5lib.parse('a (d <a href="b"> f) b (<a href="c">) d <a href="d"> d(<a href="e">)')
tokens = []
for element in document.getiterator():
    tokens.append((element.tag[element.tag.index('}')+1:], element))
    if element.text is not None:
        for char in element.text:
            tokens.append(('text', char))

state = 'OUT_OF_PARENTHESIS'
for token_type, value in tokens:
    if state == 'OUT_OF_PARENTHESIS':
        if token_type == 'a':
            state = 'GOT_AN_A_OUT_OF_PARENTHESIS'
            print(value.attrib)
            continue
    if state == 'OUT_OF_PARENTHESIS':
        if token_type == 'text' and '(' in value:
            state = 'IN_PARENTHESIS'
            continue
    if state == 'IN_PARENTHESIS':
        if token_type == 'text' and ')' in value:
            state = 'OUT_OF_PARENTHESIS'
            continue
    if state == 'GOT_AN_A_OUT_OF_PARENTHESIS':
        if token_type == 'a':
            print(value.attrib)
```